# Material UI Input Autocomplete not working in React.js

Tags: reactjs, input, material-ui

When I try to import Autocomplete exactly from the documentation: 
https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/ i get the following error message:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@material-ui/lab/esm/useAutocomplete/useAutocomplete.js
Attempted import error: 'unstable_useId' is not exported from '@material-ui/core/utils' (imported as 'useId').
```

react code:

```
/* eslint-disable no-use-before-define */
import React from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';

export const MyTeamShiftPlanInput = () => {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />}
    />
  );
}

// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top100Films = [
  { title: 'The Shawshank Redemption', year: 1994 },
  { title: 'The Godfather', year: 1972 },
  { title: 'The Godfather: Part II', year: 1974 },
  { title: 'The Dark Knight', year: 2008 },
  { title: '12 Angry Men', year: 1957 },
  { title: "Schindler's List", year: 1993 },
  { title: 'Pulp Fiction', year: 1994 },
  { title: 'The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King', year: 2003 },
  { title: 'The Good, the Bad and the Ugly', year: 1966 },
  { title: 'Fight Club', year: 1999 }
];
```

current versions of MUI:

```
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.10",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.49",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
```

Comment: I suggest you delete node_modules folder and install everything from beginning. Everything seems to be ok with your code.

Comment: This seems to be 'wrong peer dependency' issue with latest MUI version as per their github discussions forum. Try using 4.8 instead.

Comment: thanks, @LazarNikolic. This worked perfectly! I feel kinda stupid now for wasting 1.5 hours on troubleshooting this.

Comment: @WageeshaR i also read that but after reinstalling everything works great.

Answer (score 2):

Its kind of bug on current tags so far, you could try to change your @material-ui/lab module's version

From:

```
"@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.49"
```

To:

```
"@material-ui/lab": "4.0.0-alpha.46"
```

Comment: Thank you, it solved my issue. To others encountering the same issue, take note that there's no caret (^) character in front of "4.0.0-alpha.46"

Answer (score 0):

This is in addition to @Dhika's answer above.

His solution didn't work the first time I tried because I failed to notice there is no caret symbol in front of the version `'"4.0.0-alpha.46"'`.

To fix the issue

1. run `rm -rf node_modules/` to remove the node_modules folder
2. open `package.json` and look for `"@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.XX"`
3. modify the current version to `"@material-ui/lab": "4.0.0-alpha.46"`
4. run `npm install`
5. run `npm start`